# Using Docker Webmin Guest to administer Host

Tags: webserver, file-server, webmin

I'm running a Raspberry pi with HypriotOS. I want to be able to administer simple tasks via a GUI internal and remotely( mostly directory/ file sharing related) . I have docker installed and also a docker webmin.

Is it recommend to use the docker based webmin to administrate the OS or should I just install webmin directly.

If it is a good idea then what areas should I look at in setting up the container to manage it properly?

Answer (score 1):

The job of a container is to isolate/separate whatever you run on it from the host.

If you want to install a known solution to manage the system that needs to manipulate files and services directly, that solution won't work if it can't see the files and manipulate the services ; so you do not install your webmin in a container.

Obviously, there might be exceptions to this rule, for instance, installing a DNS server on a Docker container and then installing webmin there just to manage the DNS.